# Table of means and sds using dply

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to print out grouped means, and sds using dplyr in R(i.e. what one would observe in many randomised controlled trial reports where baseline demographics are reported for the placebo and drug arms). At the moment I have:

```
group_summary<- df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise_at( vars(age, iq), c(mean, sd), na.rm=TRUE)

t(group_summary)
```

which places the sds under the means:

```
                                [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        
group                           "drug1"     "drug2"       "placebo"
age (x, ...) ...             "22.72436" "25.06164" "23.54394"  
weight (x, ...) ...           "57.97143" NA         "64.66667"  
age (x, na.rm = FALSE) ...   "3.793276" "3.930634" "4.623405"  
weight (x, na.rm = FALSE) ... "16.03617" NA         "15.44099"
```

when ideally what I would like is something more along the lines of:

```
                            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        
group                           "drug1"     "drug2"       "placebo"
age (x, ...) ...             "22.7(3.8)" "25.1(3.9)" "23.5(4.6)"  
weight (x, ...) ...           "56.0(16.0)" NA         "64.7(15.4)"
```

Grateful for any advice, although a tidyverse method would be ideal if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to build on @Pete's answer. If you want to do this for several variables say a, b, c and d, do this..

```
library(tidyverse)

df%>%
   group_by(grouping.variable)%>%
     summarise_at(vars(a,b,c,d), funs(paste0(format(round(mean(., na.rm = T), y), 
                                                nsmall = y),"(",format(round(sd(., na.rm = T), y), nsmall = y) ,")")))%>%
gather(Variable, Value, -grouping.variable)%>%
spread(grouping.variable, Value)
```

I don't quite like how `t()` works. I like to use `gather` and `spread` from the `tidyr` package.

I hope this gives you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
df1 <- df %>%
    group_by(grouping.variable) %>%
    summarise(#x = variable, y = number of decimal places
    mean.sd.x = paste0(format(round(mean(x), y), 
        nsmall = y),"(",format(round(sd(x), y), nsmall = y) ,")"))
```

Comment: Thanks this work well for a single variable. Is there an efficient way to run this for e.g. 20 variables (age, height, iq etc)

Comment: I just manually repeat the last line e.g. mead.sd.age = ...., mean.sd.weight = ..... there may well me a more time efficient way.